# CakePHP 3.x: check if the cache is valid

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

My application has `Post` model. Users can set a future datetime for the `created` field, this allows to schedule the publication of the posts.

Now, using `afterDelete()` and `afterSave()` methods, each time a post is added/edited/deleted:

1. I empty the post cache;
2. I take the `created` value of the first post among those to be published in the future and I save this value in the cache.

This value indicates the datetime up to which the current post cache is still valid.

Now, I need this: when a `find()` for posts is executed, if I'm using the cache, empty the post cache.

Where can I get it?

---

**EDIT**
I could have posts with a future date, so I have to retrieve only posts with the current date:

```
$query = $this->Posts->find('all')
->where(['created <=' => new Time()]);
```

But now, with this query, how can I use a little cache?

I can do this (`PostsTable`):

```
public function afterDelete(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \Cake\ORM\Entity $entity, \ArrayObject $options) {
    $this->setNextToBePublished();
}

public function afterSave(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \Cake\ORM\Entity $entity, \ArrayObject $options) {
    $this->setNextToBePublished();
}

public function setNextToBePublished() {        
    $next = $this->find()
        ->select('created')
        ->where(['created >' => new Time()])
        ->order(['created' => 'ASC'])
        ->first();

    Cache::write('next_to_be_published', empty($next->created) ? FALSE : $next->created->toUnixString(), 'posts');
}
```

Now, every time I add/edit/delete a post, is cached the timestamp of the first post to be published with a future date.

Now I add a method to check if the cache is still valid and to empty the check (`PostsTable`):

```
public function checkIfCacheIsValid() {
    //Gets from cache the timestamp of the next record to be published
    $next = $this->getNextToBePublished();

    //If the cache is not valid, it empties the cache
    if($next && time() >= $next) {
        Cache::clear(FALSE, 'posts');

        //Sets the next record to be published
        $this->setNextToBePublished();
    }
}
```

Now finally I can do this:

```
$this->Posts->checkIfCacheIsValid();

$query = $this->Posts->find('all')
->where(['created <=' => new Time()])
->cache('myposts', 'posts');
```

Note that ***this works fine*** with the `cache()` method.

So what is the problem?
I should check if the cache is valid not in the controller, but in the model.
But if I use the `cache()` method, the `beforeFind()` event is not called, it is automatically recovered the cache.

Then how can I do?

Comment: I don't really get it... you want to empty the post cache based on the value in some other cache? Like `if now > cached timestamp then delete post cache`? If so, what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: @ndm, yes. Every time I do a `find()` for posts, I want it check for cache validity and, if `now > cache timestamp`, and empties cache.

Comment: Ok, but that should be fairly easy, just read the cached timestamp, evaluate it, and delete the post cache if necessary... Obviously you know how to delete a cache, and how to save a cache, therefore I'd assume that you also know how to read a cache. So again, what exactly is it that you're struggling with?

Comment: @ndm I don't know where to insert this code or how to do this code is executed for every `find()` for posts. I tried to rewrite the `find()` method, but it is not called, if I use the cache

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere, so you're using `Query::cache()`? Could you add a short code example showing how you are retrieving the results? Finders should definitely always be invoked, however the `Model.beforeFind` event won't be triggered for cached results.

Comment: @ndm, yeah, I'm using `Query::cache()` and I was just looking for a way not to rewrite this method (because this should happen only for the `Posts` model). Soon I'll add a little code